# Problems Scraping a Page With Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-2.7, screen-scraping, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to try and scrape a page.

I am trying to follow [this](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/03/15/webscraping-with-python-and-beautifulsoup/) tutorial.

I am trying to get the contents of the following page after submitting a Stock Ticker Symbol:

http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quotetable.aspx

The tutorial is for a page with a "GET" method, my page is a "POST".  I wonder if that is part of the problem?

I want use the first text box – under where it says:

“Enter a Stock or Index symbol below for delayed quotes.”

Relevant code:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5 (Solaris 10) Gecko'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

values = {'ctl00$ctl00$AllContent$ContentMain$ucQuoteTableCtl$txtSymbol' : 'IBM' } 
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
request = urllib2.Request("http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quotetable.aspx", data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

The call does not fail, I do not get a set of options and prices returned to me like when I run the page interactively.  I a bunch of garbled HTML.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using GET instead of POST.  I was able to make it work using GET.  I just appended `?ticker=<stock symbol>` to the URL and submitted it using `urllib2.urlopen()`. From there, you can parse the result with Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Thanks for your help, David!  It still does not work for me.  Here is my code:    request = "http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quotetable.aspx?ticker=IBM"
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

    htmltext = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

Comment: Hmmmmm...  that was working when I tried it last week.  There must be something else going on here.  I'll try playing around with this some more today. Apologies if I misdirected you.

Comment: Thank you David. I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - I think I figured out the problem (and found another).  I decided to switch to 'mechanize' from 'urllib2'.  Unfortunately, I kept having problems getting the data.  Finally,  I realized that there are two 'submit' buttons, so I tried passing the name parameter when submitting the form.  That did the trick as far as getting the correct response.

However, the next problem was that I could not get BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML and find the necessary tags.  A brief Google search revealed others having similar problems.  So, I gave up on BeautifulSoup and just did a basic regex on the HTML.  Not as elegant as BeautifulSoup, but effective.

Ok - enough speechifying.  Here's what I came up with:

```
import mechanize
import re

br = mechanize.Browser()
url = 'http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quotetable.aspx'
br.open(url)
br.select_form(name='aspnetForm')
br['ctl00$ctl00$AllContent$ContentMain$ucQuoteTableCtl$txtSymbol'] = 'IBM'
# here's the key step that was causing the trouble - pass the name parameter
# for the button when calling submit
response = br.submit(name="ctl00$ctl00$AllContent$ContentMain$ucQuoteTableCtl$btnSubmit")
data = response.read()

match = re.search( r'Bid</font><span>&nbsp;\s*([0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{2})', data, re.MULTILINE|re.M|re.I)
if match:
   print match.group(1)
else:
   print "There was a problem retrieving the quote"
```